# How to find and assign an existing customer to invoice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi i have 2 models `Customer` and `Invoice`, `Customer` has 2 fields `name` and `email` and Invoice also has 2 fields `name` and `amount`.

`Customer has_many invoices`

`Invoice belongs_to customer`

I've created an import method:

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true, skip_lines: /^(?:,\s*)+$|\b(\w*Total\w*)\b/) do |row|      
      Invoice.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

is it possible to check if existing `customer.name == invoice.name` and if true to get `customer_id` and save it. 
Thank you

Comment: It is very easy to do what you are asking, but I don't think that your `customer.name` would be a unique field in the customer table. So to find the customer you should use some unique key.

Comment: they are unique, customers are companies. i'm creating the customers(companies) with name  and email and Invoice name is basically the customer name. i know that the customer exists and the names are the same i'm trying to get the association based on the name and save customer id when creating the invoice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `name` field is unique in both `customer` and `invoice` table, you can do the following -

In your `invoice` model make `belongs_to` optional - `belongs_to :customer, optional: true`

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true, skip_lines: /^(?:,\s*)+$|\b(\w*Total\w*)\b/) do |row|
    row = row.to_hash      
    invoice = Invoice.new(row)
    customer = Customer.find_by(name: row['name'])
    invoice.customer = customer if customer.present?
    invoice.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: I get this Validation failed: Customer must exist. In the invoice table is not unique a customer has more than one invoice

Comment: Now it works but there is no customer _id in the table all are null

Comment: Ya, you will have to add data to your table. I guess this is the behavior you wanted

Comment: ```Invoice Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "invoices" ("name", "num", "date", "amount", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "AMINGST LTD_Giovanni Cigala"], ["num", "190708_89"], ["date", "2019-07-08"], ["amount", 1825.0], ["created_at", "2020-02-26 12:21:16.897396"], ["updated_at", "2020-02-26 12:21:16.897396"]]``` looks like the customer_id is not passed at all  `Customer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."name" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]`

Comment: Can you check if a customer is present in your database with the same name as the invoice name?

Comment: i created a customer name 'test' and invoice name 'test'  still customer_id null

Comment: `def import
    Invoice.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Invoices imported"
  end` should i modify the method to accept customer id?

Comment: Can you paste the result of `puts row` and `puts row[:name]`

Comment: `puts row = {"name"=>"Test", "num"=>"191015_129", "date"=>"15/10/2019", "amount"=>"1200"}` and `puts row[:name] nothing`

Comment: `Customer.find_by(name: row['name']) changed :name to 'name` and works now

Comment: Thank you Gautam i appreciate it

Comment: Always happy to help.